# How do I generate a time series in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, time

***[If you're looking to generate a date series, see this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175963/2639)***

Let's say I want to generate a series for every 5 minutes for 24 hours. How do I do that in PostgreSQL?

PostgreSQL can [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) from a `timestamp`, but not from `time`.

Is it better to pick an arbitrary timestamp, or is there another way to generate the series?

Answer (score 22):

To optimize:

```
SELECT x::time
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2000-01-01'
                     , timestamp '2000-01-02'
                     , interval  '5 min') t(x);
```

The date is irrelevant, so use arbitrary timestamp constants. The cast to `time` is very cheap.
This includes lower and upper bound, so we get `'00:00'` *twice*. Use `'2000-01-01 23:59'` as upper bound to get it once only.

Related:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)

Comment: I find something about the arbitrary date to be *very* ugly. But, I was thinking it would in fact be quicker and better too.

Comment: Since the date is irrelevant, it may as well be arbitrary. It's the fastest way.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is the best way, but we can use `generate_series` to generate the min-offset from `00:00:00` and then simply call `make_interval(mins=>)` to get the interval from it.

```
SELECT make_interval(mins=>x)::time
FROM generate_series(0, 60*24-5, 5) AS t(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

I liked @EvanCarroll way, but yet another option -

```
select  x::time
from    generate_series 
            (current_date,current_date + '1 day - 1 second'::interval,'5 minute') as t(x);
```

Comment: This will only work sometimes in someplaces. It's subject to DST borking. See my [answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175964/2639) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
SELECT '00:00:00'::time + x * '1 minute'::interval
FROM generate_series(0, 60*24, 5) AS t(x);
```