# How do I generate a date series in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, date, timezone

***[If you're looking to generate a time series, see this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158907/2639)***

Let's say that I want to generate a series of dates between two dates.
 I see the function [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) provides only

```
Function                                    Argument Type                         Return Type                                                               Description
generate_series(start, stop, step interval) timestamp or timestamp with time zone setof timestamp or setof timestamp with time zone (same as argument type) Generate a series of values, from start to stop with a step size of step
```

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` for this, but **be sure to explicitly cast the arguments to "timestamp without time zone"** otherwise they will default to "timestamp with timezone". PostgreSQL overloads `generate_series` for both inputs.

## Problems with `timestamp with timezone`

You can see the drawback here.

```
SET timezone = 'America/Santiago';
SELECT generate_series(date '2016-08-15', date '2016-08-15', '1 day');    
SELECT generate_series(date '2016-08-14', date '2016-08-15', '1 day');
```

Both of the above return the same amount of days. You can see it again here.

```
SET timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
SELECT generate_series(date '2016-10-16', date '2016-10-17', '1 day');
SELECT generate_series(date '2016-10-17', date '2016-10-17', '1 day');
```

The above shows two ranges of one day.

The reason for this behavior is that these timezones have their "DST boundary at midnight, rather than a more sensible time in the small hours"

So what does it look like to "do it right",

```
SELECT generate_series(
  timestamp without time zone '2016-10-16',
  timestamp without time zone '2016-10-17',
  '1 day'
);
```

Now you can cast to date..

```
SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(
  timestamp without time zone '2016-10-16',
  timestamp without time zone '2016-10-17',
  '1 day'
) AS gs(d);
```

---

*This question and answer was inspired by a conversation with RhodiumToad on IRC (irc://irc.freenode.net/#postgresql). He altered me to this issue and provided the solution.*

## Update: two potential fixes

### Option 1: `generate_series(date,date,interval)`

Playing around, I discovered I could perhaps save the need to explicitly cast to `timestamp without time zone` by overload for `generate_series(date,date,interval)`

Here is my function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_series( t1 date, t2 date, i interval )
RETURNS setof date
AS $$
  SELECT d::date
  FROM generate_series(
    t1::timestamp without time zone,
    t2::timestamp without time zone,
    i
  )
    AS gs(d)
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now I can rerun the test case above and it's no longer fishy. These two both return the same thing,

```
SET timezone = 'America/Santiago';
SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(date '2016-08-15', date '2016-08-15', '1 day')
  AS gs(d);

SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(
  timestamp without time zone '2016-08-15',
  timestamp without time zone '2016-08-15',
  '1 day'
)
  AS gs(d);
```

As do these two,

```
SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(date '2016-08-14', date '2016-08-15', '1 day')
  AS gs(d);

SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(
  timestamp without time zone '2016-08-14',
  timestamp without time zone '2016-08-15',
  '1 day'
)
  AS gs(d);
```

### Option 2: `generate_series(date,date,int)`

Another option is to create a new function `generate_series(date,date,int)` however [you can't have both for the reasons mentioned here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/190599/2639). So pick one of these,

```
generate_series(date,date,interval)
generate_series(date,date,int)
```

If you want the second option, try this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_series( t1 date, t2 date, i int )
RETURNS setof date
AS $$
  SELECT d::date
  FROM generate_series(
    t1::timestamp without time zone,
    t2::timestamp without time zone,
    i * interval '1 day'
  )
    AS gs(d)
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

### Caveats

With review on irc, there are some problems with those ideas,

> **< johto>** `generate_series(date, date, unknown)` already works today. when you don't break it outright with the int version (e.g. `generate_series(date, date, '1 day')`) you change the return type from timestamptz to date. `(date, date, interval)` would break fewer cases, but you'd still change the output type. (it's also not obvious what should happen with  `(date, date, '1 hour')`  that currently "works" just fine)

Comment: I  wrote a closely related answer on SO yesterday with details about function type resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860. I saw this just now and added a link since your DST demo is insightful.