# Create index for WHERE COALESCE() condition

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.6, coalesce

I'm using PostgreSQL V9.6.11

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test_c ( 
          insrt_prcs_id bigint NOT NULL, 
          updt_prcs_id bigint, src_sys_id integer NOT NULL,
          load_dttm timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL, 
          updt_dttm timestamp(6) without time zone);
```

I was trying to create an `index` for the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_c             
WHERE COALESCE(u_dttm,l_dttm) > '2020-04-10 15:29:44.596311-07'
AND   COALESCE(u_dttm,l_dttm) <= '2020-04-11 15:29:44.596311-07'
```

Create `index` as:

```
create index idx_test_c  on test_c(COALESCE((updt_dttm, load_dttm)))
```

But the query planner is not scanning the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *            
FROM test_c             
WHERE COALESCE(u_dttm,l_dttm) > '2020-04-10 15:29:44.596311-07'
AND   COALESCE(u_dttm,l_dttm) <= '2020-04-11 15:29:44.596311-07'
```

```
Seq Scan on test_c as test_c (cost=0..1857.08 rows=207 width=496) (actual=5.203..5.203 rows=0 loops=1)  
Filter: ((COALESCE((test_c.updt_dttm)::timestamp with time zone, test_c.load_dttm) > '2020-04-10 15:29:44.596311-07'::timestamp with time zone) AND (COALESCE((test_c.updt_dttm)::timestamp with time zone, test_c.load_dttm) <= '2020-04-11 15:29:44.596311-07'::timestamp with time zone))
Rows Removed by Filter: 41304
```

Why is the index scan not happening?

Comment: Aside: PostgreSQL 9.6.11? Urgently consider upgrading. At least the point release. See: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strip the incorrect pair of parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_c ON test_c(COALESCE(updt_dttm, load_dttm));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc5ea71af982fbeea7319f075185ad10)*

The way you had it was effectively indexing the [composite value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.6) `(updt_dttm, load_dttm)`, `COALESCE` not doing anything.

Your second problem was revealed by the added table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test_c ( 
  insrt_prcs_id bigint NOT NULL
, updt_prcs_id  bigint
, src_sys_id    integer NOT NULL
, load_dttm     timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL
, updt_dttm     timestamp(6) without time zone   -- !!!
);
```

Why would you use different data types for `load_dttm` and `updt_dttm`? Fix that and the second problem goes away. I suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE test_c ( 
  -- ...
, load_dttm     timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
, updt_dttm     timestamp with time zone  -- !!!
);
```

Why?

You got this error:

> ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

.. because `COALESCE` must return *one* data type. `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamtz`) is the "preferred type", so `updt_dttm timestamp` is coerced to `timestamptz`, which uses a function that depends on the `timezone` setting of the current session and hence is *not* `IMMUTABLE`. And index expressions cannot involve non-IMMUTABLE functions.

Related:

- [Is timestamptz preferred when timezone logic is performed by the client?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203352/is-timestamptz-preferred-when-timezone-logic-is-performed-by-the-client/204625#204625)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

You ***could*** make the index work with your original (broken) table design by hard-coding the time zone - `'Europe/Vienna'` in my example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test_c(COALESCE(updt_dttm AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna', load_dttm));
```

Just a proof of concept. Queries hoping to use that index would have to use the same expression. Don't go there if you don't have to. Fix your table definition instead.