# Should I duplicate columns between tables to speed-up aggregations like SUM?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, aggregate, postgresql-10

I have two tables in PostgreSQL 10.12 database:

- `waste_card` (id (PK), user_id, manufacture_date, transfer_date, address_id, card_type, .. (and other card_specific_firelds)
- `wastes` (user_id, waste_card_id(FK), amount, ... (other wastes_specific_fields)

I need to frequently list and count user wastes (2 separated API endpoints) by address and manufacture_date or transfer_date

Now to list items I fire 2 queries: 1- load user cards then 2- load wastes

```
SELECT waste_cards.* 
FROM   waste_cards 
WHERE  waste_cards.user_id = $1 
       AND (waste_cards.manufacture_date < '$2') 
       AND (waste_cards.address_id = $3) 
LIMIT $4

SELECT wastes.* 
FROM   wastes 
WHERE  wastes.waste_card_id IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)
```

To just counting *amount* I fire:

```
SELECT SUM(wastes.amount) 
FROM   waste_cards 
LEFT   OUTER JOIN wastes 
       ON wastes.waste_card_id = waste_cards.id 
WHERE  waste_cards.user_id = $1 
       AND (waste_cards.manufacture_date < '$2') 
       AND (waste_cards.address_id = $3)
```

Should I add [manufacture_date, transfer_date, address_id] fields to *wastes* to speed up queries to be like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM   wastes 
WHERE  user_id = $1 
       AND address_id = $2 
       AND manufacture_date < '$3'
```

I'm on very beginning with this system. Queries are less than 150 ms. Today its about 1K users with 100-200 cards each and 2-5 wastes on each card. Not much yet but we want to add other 10-15K users next month. So I want to ask if this db schema is correct or should I change it before go live on production.

Comment: Are you having a performance problem? Or is this a premature optimisation? How much data do you have? How long are the queries taking?

Comment: I'm on very beginning with this system. Queries are less than 150 ms. Today its about 1K users with 100-200 cards each and 2-5 wastes on each card. Not much yet but we want to add other 10-15K users next month. So I want to ask if this db schema is correct or should I change it before go live on production.

Comment: Can you describe what these tables actually represent?  What is a "waste_card", and what is a "wastes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### DB design

Seems like a 1:n relationship between `waste_card` and `wastes`. *Actual* table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) would clarify.

**Do not** repeat (duplicate) the columns `user_id`, `manufacture_date`, and `address_id` in the many-table `wastes`. That would bloat your table, introduce problems with maintenance, raise the question which is the true source of information, blatantly defy normalization etc.

#### Queries

While computing a **total sum**, just use a plain `[INNER] JOIN`. Wastecards with no related entries in `waste` don't change the result and can be excluded:

```sql
SELECT SUM(w.amount) AS total_waste
FROM   waste_card wc
JOIN   wastes     w  ON w.waste_card_id = wc.id
WHERE  wc.user_id = $1 
AND    wc.manufacture_date < $2
AND    wc.address_id = $3;
```

`LEFT JOIN` makes sense to ...

- list the sum *per entry in `waste_card`*
- *and* include cards with no entries in `waste`

But then it's typically better to use a **`LATERAL`** subquery computing the sum per card. The aggregate function guarantees exactly one row from the subquery so we can just as well switch to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` (like Andriy pointed out):

```sql
SELECT wc.*  -- or better just the columns you need
     , w.sum_waste
FROM   waste_card wc
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT SUM(w.amount) AS sum_waste
   FROM   wastes w
   WHERE  w.waste_card_id = wc.id
   ) w
WHERE  wc.user_id = $1 
AND    wc.manufacture_date < $2
AND    wc.address_id = $3;
```

See:

- [JOIN (SELECT … ) ue ON 1=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35375634/939860)
- [Fastest way to count how many dates' ranges cover each date from series](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208241/fastest-way-to-count-how-many-dates-ranges-cover-each-date-from-series/208262#208262)
- [Convert right side of join of many to many into array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173831/Convert-right-side-of-join-of-many-to-many-into-array/173879#173879)

#### Covering index

To speed up either query, an index "covering" `wastes.amount` might pay (requires Postgres 11 or later):

```
CREATE INDEX your_idx_name ON wastes(waste_card_id) INCLUDE (amount);
```

For Postgres 10 or older, fall back to a multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX your_idx_name ON wastes(waste_card_id, amount);
```

See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)
- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns/190151#190151)

---

Aside:  `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` (like in your first query) produces arbitrary results. Typically you want to add `ORDER BY` to determine results.

Comment: Why does it need to be a *left* lateral join? My understanding is that the underlying `SUM` query would return a row anyway, so wouldn't `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` work just as well?

Comment: @Andriy: You are right. `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary because the aggregate query always returns a row. My train of thought was `LEFT JOIN` before I added `LATERAL` and pushed down aggregation. (Does no harm in this context, though.)