# Getting generate_series(date, date) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, errors, set-returning-functions

When I run commands like this,

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('YESTERDAY'::date, 'TODAY'::date);
SELECT * FROM generate_series('YESTERDAY'::timestamp without time zone, 'TODAY'::timestamp without time zone);
SELECT * FROM generate_series('YESTERDAY'::timestamp with time zone, 'TODAY'::timestamp with time zone);
```

I am getting errors like this,

```
ERROR:  function generate_series(date, date) does not exist
ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
```

I also get this same error when I try to [generate a date series with `timestamp without time zone`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175963/how-do-i-generate-a-date-series-in-postgresql/175964#175964)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PostgreSQL 8.4+

This is because [`generate_series` currently **requires** a `step` when the inputs are not `int`, `bigint` or `numeric` from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

```
returns: timestamp or timestamp with time zone
generate_series(start, stop, step interval)
```

As compared to

```
returns: int, bigint or numeric, step defaults to 1.
generate_series(start, stop, step DEFAULT 1)
```

To remedy, simply add a day,

```
SELECT d
FROM generate_series(
  'YESTERDAY'::date,
  'TODAY'::date,
  '1 day' -- REQUIRED STEP
) AS gs(d);
```

## PostgreSQL pre-8.3

Note: you may also get this error if you're using [PostgreSQL 8.3 or lower in which case the `generate_series` doesn't support non-numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-srf.html)

## Amazon Redshift

`generate_series` may or may not be currently supported in Amazon Redshift, which isn't really PostgreSQL anyway. If it still isn't supported you're likely to get an error with or without the `step`,

```
ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist
```

See also,

- [Amazon Redshift API Version 2012-12-01](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/redshift/latest/redshift-dg.pdf)
- [Unsupported PostgreSQL Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Many people report this to work, but the docs have not been updated to reflect that.