# Postgres: How can you select last 12 months only, and return total count of each month, even with null/empty months?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres, and my dataset is an orders table. I'm trying to learn how to show the total amount of orders per month, per user (assuming there's only one user in this case).

My dataset:

```
id, user_id, total, created_at
```

My current query:

```
SELECT
       DATE_TRUNC('month',created_at)
         AS  total_orders,
       COUNT(id) AS count
FROM orders
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month',created_at);
```

This returns:

```
Total orders | count
2021-01-01 00:00:00, 1
```

However, here's the tricky part (to me at least) - i am using this to generate some graphs. Specifically, the last 12 months. So i would like the query to return the last 12 months, and include 0 for when no orders were created. So this is expected output:

```
Total orders | count
2021-04-01 00:00:00, 0
2021-03-01 00:00:00, 0
2021-02-01 00:00:00, 0
2021-01-01 00:00:00, 1
2020-12-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-11-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-10-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-09-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-08-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-07-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-06-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-05-01 00:00:00, 0
2020-04-01 00:00:00, 0
```

How can I accomplish this? The ultimate goal is to be super lightweight so that it's not resource intensive and fast.

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your qiestion

Comment: @nbk its already there. read rather than downvote and comment meaningless stuff.

Comment: a ]mre] is clearly, that the result set expected, must have a source table(s) as it is stated in  the provided link.

Comment: as per my original message, its in the problem. It's `Total_orders`. Already solved. Thanks. @nbk

Comment: i have a similar solution, and wanted to test it, but i really don't wanted to create data as this is really your part

Comment: @nbk, ah i misunderstood you. My apologies. Feel free to post.

Comment: Hii, and welome to the forum! I think that your question is fair enough  - although some people seem to be too quick off the mark to downvote and/or vote to close! As a New Contributor, you should have been cut some slack. Just a couple of pointers: 1) **Always include your server version -with your question, either  as a tag or clearly at the beginnning 2) When you provide table data, you should also include it  as a  fiddle - i.e with DDL and DML - db.fiddle.uk is generally considered the best - this helps those trying to help  you!

Comment: 3) Your answer contains a link which is fine! However, it's normally considered good form to put the relevant code extracts into the answer itself. This is probably whey it was downvoted. You can mark your own answer as correct (after a certain time?) - this is also fine, just no points! :-) p.s. I do wish that those who downvote would leave a reason  - how else are people to learn where they're goig wrong and how to improve?

Comment: Hi @Vérace Thank you!!! Noted for future questions <3!!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a [**date dimensions**](https://duffn.medium.com/creating-a-date-dimension-table-in-postgresql-af3f8e2941ac) table which you can `JOIN` on for various date dependent goals such as this one. The **date dimensions** table typically has useful fields describing a specific date in time such as `DateOf`, `DayOf`, `MonthOf`, `YearOf`, `DayOfWeek`, `IsHoliday`, `IsWeekend`, etc. But for this specific case, you'd just simply use the `MonthOf` and `YearOf` fields in a `LEFT JOIN` from the **date dimensions** table like so:

```
SELECT
       CONCAT(DD.YearOf, '-', DD.MonthOf, '-01 00:00:00') AS  total_orders,
       COALESCE(COUNT(O.id), 0) AS count
FROM DateDimensions DD
LEFT JOIN orders O
    DD.DateOf = O.created_at
WHERE O.id = 1
GROUP BY DD.YearOf, DD.MonthOf
```

Alternatively I believe you can generate a date series with the `generate_series` function in PostgreSQL too, but I'm not super versed on how to do so. This [DBA.StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175964/150011) has a lot of good information on generating date series.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution that works great!

```
select date(d) as day, count(sales.id) 
from generate_series(
  current_date - interval '30 day', 
  current_date, 
  '1 day'
) d 
left join sales on date(sales.created_at) = d 
group by day order by day;
```

https://www.sisense.com/blog/use-generate-series-to-get-continuous-results/

This article answers the question for any future lurkers!